# How to hide identity column in EF Code First model for OData

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

This is really an EF Code First question, but sometimes the context of OData makes a difference. The question is simple. Our underlying SQL Server tables/views have Identity columns as the (surrogate) primary key. They also have a 'code' field which represent unique identifiers which users are familiar with. Simple example: CarModel: Id = 3, Code = 'Ford';
I have successfully create the EF Mode and OData to navigate using the 'Code' field as the navigation key, using Data Annotations, and the underlying tables/views have indexes on those columns, so this is acceptable. But I would really like to have the Id column as the key, and as the navigation property in the model, but not have it show up in the response. Perhaps this is where the OData part makes a difference, because I would prefer not to do any complex interception and re-shaping of the response. Setting the columns to 'private' or even 'internal' throws an error during model generation: 'Table X has no key defined'

Is it possible to define an identity column in the EF Model, but not have it part of the OData entity/response?

---

**Edit:**

So, my comment below is still valid. This is both not a good idea for identity/key columns, nor would 'hiding' them allow the model to compile correctly. However, thanks to some links from @mreyeros and a social.msdn post from Vitek Karas, here are some notes.
The System.Data.Services namespace has an `IgnorePropertiesAttribute`. It allows properties in your model to be 'hidden'. However, as Vitek says, it currently only works with the ReflectionProvider, not with EF. (And you need to make sure you are referencing the correct library if you are using a NuGet managed release.

That said, the fluent configuration API *will* work in EF/OData:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Ignore(f => f.Password);
```

However, not only does it hide a property in the response, it also hides it from the model and the database (which might be okay for read-only query models). So if you mark a navigation key as hidden, the model will not compile. And if you mark any other property as hidden, but reference it in a QueryInterceptor, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Well, after thinking about this for awhile, I realized not everything you wish for is a good idea. With OData and navigation fields, having the true identity field might not make a difference to a LINQ client, because the syntax would be `Cars.Where(c=>c.Code.Equals("Ford"))`, but it would make a huge difference for end user url queries. Instead of `http://odata/Cars('Ford')` they would have to query `http://odata/Cars?$filter=(Code eq 'Ford')` which negates fluent navigation. I think being able to include fields in your EF model, but hide them from the user is needed, but not for keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is the case but, if you apply the "ScaffoldColumn(false)" attribute to the property that you want to hide it may work.  Here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.scaffoldcolumnattribute.aspx) entry for that attribute

Comment: Thanks but no effect for OData. I believe it would hide a column on a web page that was bound to the EF model.

Comment: here is a good post that sounds similar to what you want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861282/asp-net-web-api-odata-consumers-have-free-reign-to-query-whatever-and-however.  It looks like you can potentially get around the issue by exposing your data via a custom DTO that does not include the data that you want to obfuscate from the ODATA response.

Comment: "make DTOs objects without these columns and expose them for "pre-query" to user"...not sure I understand what he is proposing...however, this does get me a different way to pose the search: how to limit the query fields or $filter...however, most of those solutions involve intercepting the query pipeline and analyzing the url...i didn't want to go for that complexity...I was hoping for a DataAnnotation that I overlooked.

Comment: So lets say in your scenario you have an EF Model with the following properties Id and Code.  You have a function which is filtering your data based on ODATA queries and returns a collection or a single entity based on the query.  Right now you are returning an object or objects of type CarModel.  You could instead create a new type, CarModelDTO, which simply contains the property "Code".  So for example lets say right now you are simply returning a CarModel based on the Code that is passed in

Comment: instead you can change your code to select the CarModel based on the query and create and return a CarModelDTO based on the result of the query.

Comment: You mean by parsing the query manually? That works for a very simple model with few fields, or a parameterized odata operation. But for an out-of-the-box odata EF setup over a view or table with many fields, that would be a lot of error-prone parsing...or am I missing something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15065/discussion-between-mdisibio-and-mreyeros)

Comment: Doing a little further research, maybe this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792162/odata-wcf-service-hide-an-element

Comment: `IgnoreProperties` is a great find, but no-go for OData. The other links are good food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is make an odata controller that returns a projected subset of the original entity.

```
//in WebApi Config Method
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<FullEntity>("FullData");
builder.EntitySet<SubsetEntity>("SubsetData");
config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());


config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "GET" }
);
SetupJsonFormatters();
config.Filters.Add(new UncaughtErrorHandlingFilterAttribute());
```

... then have two Odata Controllers one for FulLData, one for SubsetData (with different security),

```
namespace myapp.Web.OData.Controllers
{
    public class SubsetDataController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly IWarehouseRepository<FullEntity> _fullRepository;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public SubsetDataController(
            IWarehouseRepository<fullEntity> fullRepository,
            IUserRepository userRepository
            )
        {
            _fullRepository = fullRepository;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

public IQueryable<SubsetEntity> Get()
        {
            Object webHostHttpRequestContext = Request.Properties["MS_RequestContext"];
            System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal principal =
                (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)
                    webHostHttpRequestContext.GetType()
                        .GetProperty("Principal")
                        .GetValue(webHostHttpRequestContext, null);
            if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                throw new Exception("user is not authenticated cannot perform OData query");

            //do security in here

            //irrelevant but this just allows use of data by Word and Excel.
            if (Request.Headers.Accept.Count == 0)
                Request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/atom+xml");

            return _fullRepository.Query().Select( b=>
                    new SubsetDataListEntity
                    {
                        Id = b.Id,
                        bitofData = b.bitofData
                    }
          } //end of query
   } //end of class
```